# How do I top-right position an element next to a paragraph?

Tags: css, layout

Let's say my setup is like this:

```
<div style="width:200px;">
    <label for="derp">This is an arbitrary paragraph of text that happens to be a label for a form element, in my case.</label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="derp">
</div>
```

Applying `float: right;` to the checkbox positions it to the right, but I need it to push up through the text label to the top right of the container.

I seem to be losing grasp of simple concepts...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you float an element, it floats next to content that comes after it, not before. So switch the order of the label and input and it should work.